# What version(s) of Python is shipped with macOS 11 Big Sur?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

For example running macOS Catalina v10.15, I have `/usr/bin/python` giving Python 2.7.16 and `/usr/bin/python3` giving Python 3.7.3.

With macOS Big Sur v11.0, has Apple finally dropped Python 2 and made Python 3 the default?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet - currently working from home without a spare machine to try it on.

Comment: @peterjc it uses Python 2.7.16, Python 3.8.2

Comment: @YehiaAmer that's useful, thanks - but which one does "python" at the command line run?

Comment: `python` starts python 2.7.17 whereas `python3` starts python 3.8.2 as day of this comment